# What does "promotion failure" in a JVM GC log mean?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

```
2020-06-17T12:54:16.995+0800: 681976.777: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-06-17T12:54:16.995+0800: 681976.777: [ParNew (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)  (promotion failed): 1823484K->1883608K(1887488K), 0.4255307 secs]

2020-06-17T12:54:17.421+0800: 681977.202: [CMS: 952879K->532413K(2097152K), 2.9620031 secs] 2776364K->532413K(3984640K), [Metaspace: 211696K->211696K(1241088K)], 3.3881912 secs] [Times: user=3.23 sys=0.65, real=3.39 secs]
```

My question is , what does this log mean ?

```
(0: promotion failure size = 2)  (1: promotion failure size = 3)  (2: promotion failure size = 17912169)  (3: promotion failure size = 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

You didn't say which JDK/JVM you use and what garbage collection but based on what I've found it's CMS which has been deprecated a long time ago and removed in JDK 14: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/363
**You should seriously consider switching to more modern JDK / GC**.

That's said, it seems that the GC failed to "promote" objects from Youn generation to Old generation due to insufficient space (memory) in the Old gen or its fragmentation.
Here are some links where they discuss this issue:

- [Java GC Promotion Failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089233/java-gc-promotion-failures)
- [Avoiding promotion failed in Java CMS GC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599934/avoiding-promotion-failed-in-java-cms-gc/33120472)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/698858/gc-taking-big-pause-and-parnew-promotion-failed
- https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/troubleshooting-long-gc-pauses